# How to make django work with a table in a different schema in a different database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a django model which work with remote table in a remote database.

```
class CampaignSpSdRequest(models.Model):
    asins = models.CharField(max_length=200000)
    skus = models.CharField(max_length=200000, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'search\".\"CampaignSpSdRequest'
```

The issue is I get the following error:

```
INFO:root:relation "search.CampaignSpSdRequest" does not exist
INSERT INTO "search"."CampaignSpSdRequest"
```

For some reason it ads quotas also on CampaignSpSdRequest. It works with other tables, only this one has the problem. Any idea what is going on?

Correct insert statement should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO "search".CampaignSpSdRequest
```